# Symfony access Entity Manager inside EventSubscriber

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, symfony

I have an Employer profile form and I am trying to link the `State` where `Employer` is located at with a `City` this part is working alright but the FormType got so long and this feature will be required at other places of the website so I decided to move this logic inside an EventSubscriber and reuse it where ever I need it.

Problem I am having is I am trying to wrap my head around how to inject `EntityManager` inside the `EventSubscriber` class.

I know I can add the following code inside my `services.yml` and that should do it buts its not working.

```
app.form.location:
    class: AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddStateFieldSubscriber
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

This is my `EmployerProfileType` where I am calling my `addEventSubscriber` which is `AddStateFieldSubscriber()`

```
class EmployerProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add('companyName', TextType::class)
            ->add('companyProfile', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('companyLogo', FileType::class, array(
                'data_class' => null
            ));
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddStateFieldSubscriber());

    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\EmployerProfile',

        ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_emp_profile_type';
    }
}
```

This is my `AddStateFieldSubscriber` class where I need access to `EntityManager`

```
class AddStateFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    protected $em;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSubmit'
            );
    }
    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, States $province = null)
    {
        // Remove the submit button, we will place this at the end of the form later
        // Add the province element
        $form->add('state', EntityType::class, array(
                'data' => $province,
                'placeholder' => 'provide_state',
                'class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\States',
                'mapped' => false)
        );
        // Cities are empty, unless we actually supplied a province
        $cities = array();
        if ($province) {
            // Fetch the cities from specified province
            $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Cities');
            $cities = $repo->findByStates($province, array('name' => 'asc'));
        }
        // Add the city element
        $form->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
            'placeholder' => 'provide_state_first',
            'class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Cities',
            'choices' => $cities,
        ));

    }
    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        // Note that the data is not yet hydrated into the entity.
        $province = $this->em->getRepository('AdminBundle:States')->find($data['state']);
        $this->addElements($form, $province);
    }
    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $account = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // We might have an empty account (when we insert a new account, for instance)
        $province = $account->getCity() ? $account->getCity()->getStates() : null;
        $this->addElements($form, $province);
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddStateFieldSubscriber::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called
>   in
>   /Users/shairyar/Sites/clickjobboard/src/AppBundle/Form/EmployerProfileType.php
>   on line 48 and defined

I am injecting `EntityManager` via service then why do I get this error?

If inside `EmployerProfileType` I replace

`$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddStateFieldSubscriber();`
to 
`$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddStateFieldSubscriber($this->em));`

then things start working fine.

I thought in Symfony we are supposed to inject the dependencies by creating services? So how can I inject `EntityManager` inside my `AddStateFieldSubscriber()` class

What am i doing wrong? may be I am over thinking about it.

Will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Its absolutely normal behaviour. You're creating an instance of the subscriber by yourself instead of requesting it - hence the exception you got. `app.form.location` is the ID of your service, yet you're not using it.

Comment: @Artamiel thanks, yes I understood that so how to `use` it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tag your `AddStateFieldSubscriber` as kernel.event_subscriber.

Then the binding inside the form in not needed at all.

Instead you need to check for the correct form, and jump out of the event listener method if the form is not one of your forms using that subscriber, since the Event would be triggered on any form then, not only the EmployerProfileType form.

Comment: Thanks, is there any code you can share on how to check for the right form inside the event subscriber?

Comment: Sorry never did it myself. $event->getForm->getName() ?